# Remove private docker registry credentials from Spring Boot POM file

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

I want to create docker images with CI/CD (Jenkins) of my spring boot application and push the image to a private nexus docker registry.
How to avoid adding my docker credentials to POM file and have them in GIT? Where should I pass/place the credentials instead?

Or should I just push the image manually in jenkins with `docker login`, `docker push`?

I followed this tutorial (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image-example-publish) and my POM looks like this:

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>docker.example.com/library/${project.artifactId}</name>
                        <publish>true</publish>
                    </image>
                    <docker>
                        <publishRegistry>
                            <username>user</username>
                            <password>secret</password>
                            <url>https://docker.example.com/v1/</url>
                            <email>user@example.com</email>
                        </publishRegistry>
                    </docker>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use variables in your POM and pass them when calling maven. You should store the credentials in jenkins credentials manager

e.g.:

```
...
<properties>
    <DOCKER_REGISTRY/>
    <DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER/>
    <DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD/>
    <DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME>${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <name>${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}</name>
            <publish>true</publish>
        </image>
        <docker>
            <publishRegistry>
                <username>${DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER}</username>
                <password>${DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}</password>
                <url>${DOCKER_REGISTRY}</url>
            </publishRegistry>
        </docker>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Then you could call maven like this in your jenkins pipeline:

```
stage('Build Docker Image') {
    steps {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'YOUR_CREDENTIALS_ID', passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_USER')]) {
            sh "mvn -DskipTests=true spring-boot:build-image -DDOCKER_REGISTRY=SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM -DDOCKER_REGISTRY_USER=$NEXUS_USER -DDOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=$NEXUS_PASSWORD"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the credentials using Jenkins credential manager, and set them up in your mvn build command via -D parameters