# Access Maven settings.xml in pom.xml for Spring Boot Maven Plugin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I would like to access the user-specific settings (passwords, usernames etc. for a shared private repository) that are contained within the `settings.xml` in my pom.

I need these settings for the **Spring Boot Maven Plugin**, because I want to use the publish feature there (pushing a created docker image to our private docker repository).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Of course I don't want to save any user-specific passwords inside the pom.xml.

The maven documentation states that it is possible to access the settings.xml (e.g. here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#how-do-i-filter-resource-files), but it does not explain how to to that.

I expecting something like this in my pom:

```
<someTag>${userSettings.some.property}</someTag>
```

Comment: It doesn't sound right. If you need auth to publish, just add the repository in the pom and match the id tag in pom with an id in the settings.xml. You don't need to have the auth in te pom for it to work.

Comment: That because of the Spring Boot Maven Plugin. You have to specifiy username and password for this plugin to work. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.docker-registry for reference

Comment: The credentials for docker registry are by default in `$HOME/.docker` via `docker login` but not in `settings.xml`.

Comment: @khmarbaise My docker instance is already logged in (I used docker login a while ago). I can push to our registry without problems using docker push. But the spring-boot-maven-plugin doesn't seem to be able to use the already stored credentials.

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this thread: I partially solved my problem using this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680371/remove-private-docker-registry-credentials-from-spring-boot-pom-file (using environment variables when calling mvn package). But I don't like this solution because it involves fiddling around with env variables. There must be a better solution

Comment: @Walnussbär that is described in [Settings Reference: Properties](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#properties)

Comment: thanks @AndreyB.Panfilov but there are only 4 properties available using ${settings}, and they do not contain what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have following configuration for `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <name>docker.example.com/library/${project.artifactId}</name>
            <publish>true</publish>
        </image>
        <docker>
            <publishRegistry>
                <username>user</username>
                <password>secret</password>
                <url>https://docker.example.com/v1/</url>
                <email>user@example.com</email>
            </publishRegistry>
        </docker>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and do not want to store our credentials in `pom.xml` since it is available to everyone who has access to version control system. Maven way is to define `profile` in `~/.m2/setting.xml` with our credentials and and replace credentials in `pom.xml` with corresponding placeholders, like:

~/.m2/settings.xml:

```
...
<profiles>
...    
    <profile>
        <id>registry-example.com</id>
        <properties>
            <registry.username>user</registry.username>
            <registry.password>secret</registry.password>
            <registry.url>https://docker.example.com/v1/</registry.url>
            <registry.email>user@example.com</registry.email>
        </properties>
    </profile>
...    
</profiles>
...
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <name>docker.example.com/library/${project.artifactId}</name>
            <publish>true</publish>
        </image>
        <docker>
            <publishRegistry>
                <username>${registry.username}</username>
                <password>${registry.password}</password>
                <url>${registry.url}</url>
                <email>${registry.email}</email>
            </publishRegistry>
        </docker>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now, in order to tell `maven` to take into account the `profile` we have created we need to run `maven` with `-P` flag specifying id of our `profile`:

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image -Pregistry-example.com
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a solution I can accept. Works like a charm. I also like that one ist still able to pass these properties as environment variables when running mvn package, so you are not forced to use a Maven profile. Thank you very much again! :)